# How to deserialize an Bson string with"id" using BsonSerializer.Deserialize()?

Tags: c#, deserialization, bson

I am deserialize a BSON string to a C# class, and met a error.

Here is the string

```
{  
    "_typeName" : "FATPOT::Mapping::Rendering::GisSourceFile", 
    "compressionType" :  2, 
    "fileType" : 3, 
    "id" : "9f5f53d7-dc38-421e-8e2d-f419717540d1", 
    "localPath" :  "C:/Resources/Shape/GU_Reserve.dbf", 
    "name" : "GU_Reserve.dbf", 
    "stored" : true  
}
```

Here is the C# model class: GisSourceFileModel

```
public class GisSourceFileModel
    {
        [BsonElement("_typeName")]
        public string TypeName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("compressionType")]
        public int CompressionType { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("fileType")]
        public int FileType { get; set; }
     
        [BsonElement("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("localPath")]
        public string LocalPath { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("stored")]
        public bool Stored { get; set; }
    }
```

Deserialization code

```
[TestMethod]
public void BsonDeserialize_GisSourceFileModel_Should_Work()
{
    var srcStr = "{  \"_typeName\" : \"FATPOT::Mapping::Rendering::GisSourceFile\", \"compressionType\" :  2, \"fileType\" : 3, \"id\" : \"9f5f53d7-dc38-421e-8e2d-f419717540d1\", \"localPath\" :  \"C:/Resources/Shape/GU_Reserve.dbf\", \"name\" : \"GU_Reserve.dbf\", \"stored\" : true  }";
    var bsonDocument = BsonDocument.Parse(srcStr);
    var actualJsonDeserializedModel = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<GisSourceFileModel>(bsonDocument);
    Assert.IsNotNull(actualJsonDeserializedModel);
}
```

Here is the error message

```
 Message: 
Test method Mapping.Plugin.Tests.GisSourceTests.BsonDeserialize_GisSourceFileModel_Should_Work threw exception: 
System.FormatException: Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class Mapping.Plugin.BLL.Models.GisSourceFileModel.
```

From the error message, the "id" is the cause of the error.
Can I have any hint or input to fix the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer
Change GisSourceFileModel 's "Id" to any other name to make it work.

e.g.

```
public string Identification { get; set; }
```

Feel "Id" is a kind of reserved keyword, or maybe it's a bug for BsonSerializer